How to get updated values in NiceGUI
I'm writing a NiceGUI frontend for my Python code.
This is my first time writing frontend, and I'm not very used to web-framework concepts.
Essentially, the use of this frontend is to ask to user to insert the following variables (I know range is not a good variable name):
variants_text: str
keywords_text: str
seed: int | None
min_articles: int | None
max_articles: int | None
range: int | None
limit: int | None

This is the code I have written so far (the only dependecy is nicegui, and you need a dummy .txt file to pass Step1):
from nicegui import ui

class ArticleRetrieval:

    def __init__(self):

        self.page_title = "Article Retrieval"
        self.headers()
        
        self.stepper = ui.stepper().props("vertical").classes("w-full")

        self.step1_title = "Add input files"
        self.step2_title = "Add optional arguments"
        self.step3_title = "Retrieve articles"

        self.variants_uploaded = False
        self.variants_text = None

        self.keywords_uploaded = False
        self.keywords_text = None

        self.seed = None
        self.min_articles = None
        self.max_articles = None
        self.range = None
        self.limit = None

        self.positive_integer_validator = {
            "You can only insert a non-negative integer": self._acceptable_num
        }
    
    def _acceptable_num(self, n) -> bool:
        return (n is None) or (n == int(n) and n >=0)
    
    def _variants_uploaded(self, e):
        self.variants_uploaded = True
        self.variants_text = e.content.readlines()
        if self.keywords_uploaded is True:
            self.step1_next_button.visible = True  

    def _keywords_uploaded(self, e):
        self.keywords_uploaded = True
        self.keywords_text = e.content.readlines()
        if self.variants_uploaded is True:
            self.step1_next_button.visible = True

    def _update_seed(self, e):
        self.seed = e.value
        self._step2_next_button_visibility()

    def _update_min_articles(self, e):
        self.min_articles = e.value
        self._step2_next_button_visibility()

    def _update_max_articles(self, e):
        self.max_articles = e.value
        self._step2_next_button_visibility()

    def _update_range(self, e):
        self.range = e.value
        self._step2_next_button_visibility()

    def _update_limit(self, e):
        self.limit = e.value
        self._step2_next_button_visibility()

    def _step2_next_button_visibility(self):
        if all(
            self._acceptable_num(x) for x in [
                self.seed,
                self.min_articles,
                self.max_articles,
                self.max_articles,
                self.limit,
            ]
        ):
            self.step2_next_button.set_visibility(True)
        else:
            self.step2_next_button.set_visibility(False)

    def _ask_confirm(self):
        ui.markdown(
            f"""
            ##### DO YOU CONFIRM THIS DATA?<br>

            **variants**: {self.variants_text}<br>
            **keywords**: {self.keywords_text}<br>
            **seed**: {self.seed}<br>
            **min\\_articles**: {self.min_articles}<br>
            **max\\_articles**: {self.max_articles}<br>
            **range**: {self.range}<br>
            **limit**: {self.limit}<br>
            """
        )

    def headers(self):
        ui.page_title(self.page_title)
        ui.markdown(f"#{self.page_title}")
    
    def step1(self):
        with ui.step(self.step1_title):
            ui.upload(
                label="Variants (.txt file)",
                max_files=1,
                auto_upload=True,
                on_upload=self._variants_uploaded,
            ).props("accept=.txt").classes("max-w-full")

            ui.upload(
                label="Keywords (.txt file)",
                max_files=1,
                auto_upload=True,
                on_upload=self._keywords_uploaded,
            ).props("accept=.txt").classes("max-w-full")
        
            with ui.stepper_navigation():
                self.step1_next_button = ui.button(
                    "NEXT",
                    icon="arrow_forward_ios",
                    on_click=self.stepper.next
                )
                self.step1_next_button.visible = False

    def step2(self):

        with ui.step(self.step2_title):
            
            ui.number(
                label="Seed",
                validation=self.positive_integer_validator,
                on_change=self._update_seed
            ).props("clearable")
            ui.number(
                label="Minimum articles",
                validation=self.positive_integer_validator,
                on_change=self._update_min_articles
            ).props("clearable")
            ui.number(
                label="Maximum articles",
                validation=self.positive_integer_validator,
                on_change=self._update_max_articles
            ).props("clearable")
            ui.number(
                label="Range",
                validation=self.positive_integer_validator,
                on_change=self._update_range
            ).props("clearable")
            ui.number(
                label="Limit",
                validation=self.positive_integer_validator,
                on_change=self._update_limit
            ).props("clearable")

            with ui.stepper_navigation():
                self.step2_back_button = ui.button(
                    "BACK",
                    icon="arrow_back_ios",
                    on_click=self.stepper.previous,
                )
                self.step2_next_button = ui.button(
                    "NEXT",
                    icon="arrow_forward_ios",
                    on_click=self.stepper.next
                )
                self.step2_next_button.visibility = False

    def step3(self):
        with ui.step(self.step3_title):
            self._ask_confirm()
            with ui.stepper_navigation():
                ui.button(
                    "BACK",
                    icon="arrow_back_ios",
                    on_click=self.stepper.previous,
                )
                ui.button(
                    "RUN",
                    icon="rocket_launch",
                    on_click=lambda x: None  # HERE I WILL PERFORM THE ACTUAL JOB
                )
    
    def run(self):
        with self.stepper:
            self.step1()
            self.step2()
            self.step3()
        ui.run()

ArticleRetrieval().run()

My question is about the _ask_confirm method.
It always prints the initial values of attributes, the ones I've defined in the __init__ method (i.e. all None).

I would like that string to be updated every time I update values in Step1 and Step2.
The thing I don't understand is that if, for example, I change the _update_seed method like this
def _update_seed(self, e):
    print(self.seed)
    self.seed = e.value
    print(self.seed)
    self._step2_next_button_visibility()

It prints the updated values.
I hope someone can help me. Thank you very much.

This is quite a lot of code. It would help a lot if you could boil it down to a minimum example without dependencies to additional txt files. Reducing the problem is often the first step to solving it.

The whole code is there just to make it run. As I said, "My question is about the _ask_confirm method."
